# Solved - Backspace misbehaving in Excel 2010 Comment Box

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, comments

UPDATE Feb 5th 2022. Eventually found that the problem of the cursor in a Comment box remaining in place after a Backspace (so the character that was originally to its right was now to the left of the cursor) was somehow related to having a very large amount of text in the comment box (roughly equivalent to a full A4 page of text). On deleting the bulk of the text (an accumulation of to-do jobs) the backspace reverted to behaving as it should - as well as deleting a character, it also moved one space left

I have, for a long time, used large comment boxes in Excel 2010 under WIN7, to hold an ongoing to-do list.

Having just resolved one problem (detail below) I'm now finding that when I key characters, they appear one_at_a_time, slowly (about 0.5 secs apart) rather than continuously (as far as the eye can see).

This problem occurs in all parts of the comment box.

This problem does not affect other comment boxes in the same worksheet, so it seems to be somehow buried in the content.

I cannot find any keyboard keys that affect the problem, nor any relevant answers here (the question could be posed in many different ways).

I have tried copying the (quite large amount of) content into a clean new comment, but it seems to take this fault with it, even if I copy the comment contents into MS Word and then back into a new comment.

There's too much content to simply retype it all, unless there's no other option (the problem is too irritating to live with for the future).

Task manager shows me that CPU and Memory usage are within normal range, and if  I close down almost everything running, the problem doesn't go away.

Any helpful suggestions will be gratefully received - Thank you

**Resolved initial problem**: the cursor in the same comment not moving on hitting backspace (leaving it after the character that followed the one deleted). it eventually cleared after copying the content into another clean new comment, via a copy to Word, though I'm not sure just how that helped. It is a problem that recurs, so again, any further suggestions on this one also gratefully received.

Comment: You have already shown that the problem persists if you copy the content to a new comment. You could narrow down the problem by copying the first half of the text; if the problem exists in the new comment, it is caused by the first half of the text, otherwise it is caused by the second. Repeat with smaller parts of the problem text until you spot the problem or have narrowed it down to a section that is small enough to retype.

Comment: @Blackwood. Strange: it persisted in both halves. However, I copied the whole misbehaving comment into a clean comment in a new work**book** this time, and then when I copied it back into a new comment in the **original** file, it was fine. When I then went back an earlier version of the original corrupt file, the problem had disappeared from there too. Very odd! Again thanks - iS